# SQL for a generated table with column 1 a sequence of numbers and column 2 a running sum

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

What would be the SQL (standard, or any major variant) to produce a table like the following?

```
1   1   -- 1
2   3   -- 2+1
3   6   -- 3+2+1
4   10  -- 4+3+2+1
5   15  -- 5+4+3+2+1
6   21  -- 6+5+4+3+2+1
```

... ...

The second column is the sum of the numbers in the first.

I couldn't get past this:

```
select rownum from all_objects  where rownum <= 10;
```

Which produces column 1 (PL/SQL)

Tried to think on the following lines but clearly it is wrong, even syntactically:

```
select rownum, count(t2.rownum)
 from 
 (select sum(rownum) from all_objects  where rownum <= 10) t2,
 all_objects  
 where rownum <= 10;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a cumulative sum:

```
select rownum, sum(rownum) over (order by rownum)
from all_objects
where rownum <= 10;
```

I wasn't sure this would actually work on `rownum`, but it [does](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=dfaea859b8b6da0162c5351428be0bad).

Answer (score 1):

It is simple [math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression):

```
select rownum, rownum * (rownum + 1) / 2
from all_objects
where rownum <= 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to hit the `all_objects` view; you could use a hierarchical query:

```
select level as position, sum(level) over (order by level) as running_sum
from dual
connect by level <= 10;

  POSITION RUNNING_SUM
---------- -----------
         1           1
         2           3
         3           6
         4          10
         5          15
         6          21
         7          28
         8          36
         9          45
        10          55
```

or using @forpas' arithmetic-series method:

```
select level as position, level * (level + 1) / 2  as running_sum
from dual
connect by level <= 10;

  POSITION RUNNING_SUM
---------- -----------
         1           1
         2           3
         3           6
         4          10
         5          15
         6          21
         7          28
         8          36
         9          45
        10          55
```

Or recursive subquery factoring (11gR2+):

```
with rcte (position, running_sum) as (
  select 1, 1 from dual
  union all
  select position + 1, running_sum + position + 1
  from rcte
  where position < 10
)
select * from rcte
order by position;

  POSITION RUNNING_SUM
---------- -----------
         1           1
         2           3
         3           6
         4          10
         5          15
         6          21
         7          28
         8          36
         9          45
        10          55
```